# Shortcode are not working in Option tree textarea

Tags: shortcode, theme-options

I am using option tree. In textarea, i place shortcode

```
[layerslider id="1"]
```

its not working, i also found same post replied by plugin author 
[allow shortcodes in textarea in option tree](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-optiontree-allow-shortcodes-in-textarea)

applied the

```
do_shortcode('[layerslider]');
```

still no solution

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-optiontree-allow-shortcodes-in-textarea/

Comment: @IsmailFarooq I have got the answer mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution.

you can use shortcode *e.g.* **[layerslider id="1"]** in textarea/textbox and call it by the **name** to the textarea/textbox use in option tree function files

*e.g.*

```
get_option_tree( 'textboxname');
```

Answer (score 1):

It will do.

```
do_shortcode(get_option_tree( 'textboxname' ));
```

The code will get the value whatever it is form optiontree textbox and execute the shortcode manager on it. If that string contains any shortcode it will be repalced by the output.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not just dump code but explain how and why this solves the issue at hand.

Comment: @kraftner bro, its a simple code